# Curl request getting timed out when sent from PHP server but working fine from localhost and yes curl is enabled and working on other domains

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap a page of a particular domain so I am spoofing a browser request in curl which is working fine on localhost but when I use the same request on server hosted on forge it gets timed out and gives Curl 7 connection timed at port 443 or 80 error

Comment: Perhaps you need to be authorized by local proxy. Check connection settings and set up curl settings like CURLOPT_PROXY*